# Android and Ios App badge count is behaving differently when in the app in the background and not have control over it

Tags: android, ios, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

In Android, Firebase handles the count incrementally, and in Ios replaces the previous count with the new one, so when the FPNs return count=1 the first time android=ios=1 but the second time FPNs return 2 android=1+2=>3 and ios just swipes the 1 with 2 which is 2.

How to control the ios and android badge counts?

versions
firebase_messaging: ^14.1.4
firebase_core: ^2.4.0